# Allowing QGIS atlas to show html box in different location on some Atlas pages

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have created a QGIS Atlas, and that's contains a html box. This box is always on the same location on each atlas pages. Is there any way to custom locate the html box on some atlas pages?

I created my legend in a html box and a map view (full page) on a print composer (this means my html box is on/overlapping the mapview), the map view is controlled by atlas. In the atlas preview I have couple of pages and the html box is always on the same position on all of the pages, but sometimes it would be better to move somewhere else because it's overlapping whit some mapview features. Is it possible to do that?